# sequences and periodicity in the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a following lower bounded sequence, where the $k^{th}$ term is $a_k$:

(1) $a_k \ge a_{min}$,     (2) if $p$ is a positive integer, then $a_{pk} \le \min\{a_k, a_p\}$.

Are there any eventual periodicity results for such a sequence?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. People here like to see what you have tried. Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: What is $a_{min}$?

Comment: a_min is a positive lower bounding constant for the sequence. The sequence is also upper bounded.

Comment: Subsequential limit set is compact - is it periodic or almost periodic?

Comment: I should have said for any given epsilon, does there exist positive integers N, T satisfying |a_{n+T}-a_n|<epsilon